# To calculate sum of c(1) + ... + c(i) in excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have one column, say c.  I want to have a new column with value d(i) = c(1) + ... + c(i - 1) + c(i). Is it possible in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I used a spreadsheet, but something like:

```
    C     D
1         =SUM($C$1:C1)
2
3
```

And then you drag the cell with the sum formula down with the crosshair.  The cell C1 will be fixed but the second "argument" will increase.